# How to create an animated website like Ba Ba Dum

Tags: html, animated

My wife's birthday is coming up and I would like to create a website similar to
 Ba Ba Dum: https://babadum.com/

I have learned HTML5 in school but never learned about its ability to create animated websites.

How do I go about making a website like that? Do I have to use Flash or is it fully rendered with HTML5? Looking at the source code revealed something about google api and ajax and jquery, are they essential to making an animated website like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Then, You have much to learn and need much time. I think it's not Flash. CSS3 and HTML5.

Comment: As it stands, this question is much too broad. Please review the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) documentation for more information on how to ask a question that is better suited to this site's Q&A style format...

Comment: I think I am making progress! Just found W3school's tutorial on Jquery. I think it might be what I need. http://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/jquery_animate.asp

Comment: The fancy animations on the website you reference are done with `canvas` . There are specific libraries for that like kinect.js and many others. Canvas is not exactly a beginner topic though, so you're better of with simple css and js animations to get started. I would advise you not to use jQuery for animations though, but something like velocity.js that uses more modern techniques and has much better performance. Also be careful with w3schools http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: When is your wife's birthday again? :D

Answer (score 3):

Although your question is way, way too broad, I'll try to help.

The site you linked -as far as I can tell- is made HTML, CSS and JavaScript. There are less and less sites that use Flash, and you shouldn't use that either - it's starting to die out, at last.

Be prepared to research a lot - you'll have to learn about CSS3 (style, position and animations), JavaScript ("JS", it's very useful for sites filled with interactive elements - sounds, videos, etc) and jQuery (special JS library, it contains several dozens of pre-written functions that can make web development easier and faster). If I were you, I'd visit [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/), it's a website that teaches these languages, and for free. Completing those courses shouldn't take more than 20-30 hours, and it would give you a solid base to start from.

Of course, the required skill level depends on the type of site you want to build. A simple, animated website can be built with only HTML and CSS3. For more complex sites you most likely have to use JS and jQuery.

Here is what should you do:

- Start out with a fix idea: you want to know what you want to create, especially because (probably) this will be your first serious project. Doodle on paper, write down your ideas about what should happen if you press a button, for example.
- Divide the site into smaller pieces: you won't finish it one day, so you should focus on building the site step by step. Create a button, use CSS to make it fancy then give it some animation. If you are satisfied, you can move on to the next part.
- Research: most likely you won't be the first person to do the things you want to do the way you want to do. Use google and you'll find hundreds of different tutorials, starting from simple things (building a layout) to more complex one (pure CSS animations, canvas, etc). If you stuck, Stackoverflow will help, but you'll have to be more specific with your questions. This current question is bad, and I'm only writing this response because I too know about needing help and realizing no one will help me just because my question is too broad. And I don't have anything better to do at 23:40 :) Try to find out if someone already asked your question - it's possible, and that way you may find the answer(s) instantly.
- Study source codes: if you are using Chrome, you click on any element on a site to view it's code - you just have to select "Inspect element" from the context menu (there are other ways to do it with other browsers). It will show you the HTML, the CSS properties and even the relevant JS code. You can modify these values (especially useful with CSS) if you want to experiment a little - these changes are only visible for you and deleted when you refresh the page. This method is useful if you found the perfect button animation you want to include on your page but don't know how to do it.
- Backup your work! Create a backup copy of your site every day, so if you mess something up badly (happens to everyone, especially if you're in a hurry like often I am) you don't have to start from scratch. It happened to me before, and if you are using other people's code (from tutorials, I'm not talking about stealing) it might happen to you too.

Also, good luck!

Comment: even better then backups would be a real vcs with full history like git. Github or Bitbucket are very easy to use and should be a must for every self respecting developer.

Comment: Nice post! Please add SVG to the listing of technologies used by that site

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few places I'd recommend going to, all of these have helped me and are a good place to start.

- Codecademy - http://www.codecademy.com/learn

  For basic HTML, CSS, JavaScript and jQuery lessons. Best site on the web, I say. Also, recently released AngularJS lessons, which are quite good.
- Code school - https://www.codeschool.com/

  Provides good AngularJS lessons, which you should do once you've finished the Codecademy ones.
- Egghead - https://egghead.io/

  Good for AngularJS lessons and HTML5 canvas lessons. The HTML5 canvas lessons are brilliant, the presenter is a genius.

What all these things are.

HTML5 canvas - A method of drawing graphics to the screen. Great for video games and animations. I've actually made the loading effect of that site you listed with canvas.

jQuery - A JavaScript library, which is a bunch of predefined functions for ease in coding. It is good for special effects and event listeners.

AngularJS - An awesome library which makes displaying data so much easier. Great for fast single page apps.